# Electron Login / Register etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, connection, electron

I am pretty new to making Electron apps. After asking a question on Stack Overflow *([Properly Using Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557586/properly-using-electron))* I followed the advice I was given and created a desktop application in Electron.

*I have another app created in NodeJS that handles my database
methods.*

I am not sure where to start with this problem, as there are hundreds of options online, and I am not sure which ones suit my needs.

**Should I:**

- *Have a client application made in Electron and a server made in NodeJS that handles the database*
  *OR*
- *Have a client application and connect to my database from Electron?*

If I were to do it *all* in a client app, I think that would cause major security issues, so I am unsure what to do. The problem is as simple as creating a login/system application, but I have no idea how to incorporate it into Electron.

Where do I start? How do I approach this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you need is a login and your server already manages the database I would keep this logic on the server. This is also something the answer to your previous question states.

- Your client sends a POST request containing the username, password over HTTPS (SSL encryption), this can happen in the renderer process.
- Your Server checks if the password and user are valid.
- Server returns your client if the authentification was valid, via token.

  - Either the main process (Electron-NodeJs) persists the token (File)
  - Or the Render process (Electron-Chromium) persists the token (Web Storage)

This is the most simple example which is neglecting advanced security concerns, if you want to make it more secure you definitely should look for general advise about web security like crypto-pbkdf2 and how to handle the tokens. But this is not electron specific.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I finally understand how it's supposed to be done. Thank you very much. Just a few more quick question. You suggested using JWT, if I'm not mistaken. How should I, in general, go about sending the token back to the client? Is there any specific ways or?

Comment: JWT is just one way to do it I didn't want to be over specific :) Since electrons renderer process is just chrome you just wait for the server to answer with the token, like in the good old PHP days. https://jwt.io/ will help you to understand how a JWT token works, or you can use something like passport.js to help you with that.

Comment: Not sure if you will see this or not, but another quick question: if I were to use JWT for authentication, would it be secure to connect to a db from the client just to grab stuff from other collections (such as posts etc.)? Or should the server handle that aswell and some how pass it back to the user? I'm pretty sure that returning everything to the user with JWT wouldn't be the best option as I have a lot of data. Will it be safe to connect to the database from the client? (of course after the server handles the authentication)

Comment: This depends on how much data is transferred, how fresh the data has to be and what you want to be cached. For example, posts are very static therefore simple to cache, running a filter combination (Like Car color, Car model, Maximal mileage) over a database is not simple to cache since the database could change at any given time. You could encrypt the cache but normally you wouldn't since your PC/Laptop has this layered down in the user administration. (PC Login, Permissionsystems etc.). Also, I would not make the DB accessible from remote, the server should handle that.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure I understand what you mean. If I were, for example, to move 2500 strings from the server to the client, what would be a good way of achieving that? Also, sorry for bothering you, I'm still pretty new to this :)

Comment: No worries, I think it is good to ask ;) You could use IndexedDB or Web Storage, IndexedDB seems like the better way to do it since it is superior over Web Storage. The advantage over using something like the sqlite package is that it is natively implemented in Chromium (C/C++) and does not require the nodeJS stack, resulting in less process blocking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160534/discussion-between-grim-reaper-and-hans-koch).